# Longest Path through Circles with Varying Radii

Tags: calculus, geometry, optimization, euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization

**Problem**: Given a starting point $x_0$, an ending point $x_{n+1}$, and a collection of intermediate, ordered circles with centers and radii: $\{(o_1,r_1),\dots,(o_n,r_n)\}$, my goal is to find $x^*=(x_0,x_1^*,\dots,x_n^*,x_{n+1})$ that corresponds to the longest (piecewise) linear path through all these circles (one point per circle). In the simple example below, I want to connect $A$ to $F$ by finding 2 points, one inside the circle with center $B$ and another point within the circle with center $E$, that form the longest (piecewise) linear path.

[image: circle problem]

**Attempt**: The problem can be more formally written as

$$\max_{x_1,\dots,x_n} \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \lVert x_{i+1}-x_i\rVert_1^1$$

subject to the constraint that $\lVert x_i-o_i\lVert_2^2\leq r_i^2$, i.e. the $i$th point is contained in the $i$th circle. This is a convex programming problem with quadratic constraints, so I can apply some subgradient-based algorithm or use cvxpy/another solver to get close to the solution.

**Question**: But is there an exact solution that can be found without employing iterative methods? Or can the problem be formulated as another problem which requires the use of iterative methods?

Comment: I am tempted to say no, on the ground that you cannot reduce this issue to a set of local optimizations : being given a certain path, the slightest modification you do on one of its points can influence all the other points.

Comment: Why not just go through centers?

Comment: Calling the path "linear" means that it follows a straight line from one end to the other. "Piecewise linear" or "polygonal" are the most common descriptions for the path you want.

Comment: Is the sequence of circles to visit predefined or is a kind of traveling salesman problem?

Comment: Not TSP - I give the arcs beforehand - i.e. $(x_0,x_1),\dots,(x_n,x_{n+1})$ where $x_i$ is in circle $i$.

Comment: @Moti Because it's not optimal in general? Consider a simple case with just two points $x_0=(1,0)$ and $x_1=(0,1)$ and the unit circle centered at the origin - then going through the center is definitely not optimal

Comment: @PaulSinclair Corrected now - thanks for noting

Comment: Now I am not sure I have well understood your question : when you say "in the circles **containing** $B$ and $E$" : do you mean "**on** the circles with centers $B$ and $E$" ? Sure it is not the **disks** ?

Comment: I realize the ambiguity sorry - I mean each point per circle to be placed must satisfy the constraint that $\lVert x_i-o_i\rVert_2^2\leq r_i^2$

Comment: When I say I give the arcs, I mean that I decide the circles and their order beforehand to choose from. This isn't TSP where the graph is initially undirected.

Comment: This longest path is surely in the **convex hull** of the disks. Have you considered this direction ?

Comment: I believe you are right, but I don't immediately see how that can be applied here frankly